Unable to Migrate AWS Sagemaker Notebook instance of Amazon Linux 1(AL1) type to Amazon Linux 2 (AL2)
I have AWS sagemaker notebook instances of Amazon Linux 1 type (notebook-al1-v1) and its in Stopped state. As AWS is not supporting AL1type notebook anymore, i want to migrate it to AL2 type. I followed AWS official blog (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/migrate-your-work-to-amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-with-amazon-linux-2/) to migrate it but in order to do that I have to start the notebook at some point in the blog steps, which is not possible if the instance is in Stopped state, according to AWS's developer guide.

Also I do not have any backup of the code which was running in the notebook.
Is there any way I can migrate the existing notebookfro Amazon Linux 1 to Amazon Linux 2 type instance and make it functional as before? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You can simply run the script here - https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/blob/master/scripts/migrate-ebs-data-backup/on-start.sh on your notebook terminal, instead of setting it up as an LCC and restarting the notebook. This will back up the data to S3, and you can then create a new notebook and restore your files from S3 following the blog.
